# Does dry skin break wudu? (Repeat)

Tags: salat, wudu, mistake

This is a copy of another question I deleted. That question was unclear and when edited it seemed nobody got to see the edited version. Therefore, here is a more clear version:

Basically I done wudu and prayed my namaz zuhr and asr. After this I looked in the mirror and realised I had dry skin on my nose. I went to the bathroom washed the dry skin and realised after that it returns to its dry state and nothing changes.So it seems that I shed skin and then new skin is exposed that has no water on it. I don't know if this has happened before the wudu or after so is my wudu invalid? If so what should I do with my Zuhr and Asr prayer?

Comment: Reposting the same question is usally disliked on SE. As we are a Q&A site not a typical internet forum.

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't delete a question as in fist place your first posting may have lacked a lot of information which once added may help answering. by deleting it you disclosed again the whole attempts to improve and clarify your post,

Comment: Sorry I thought that people didn't view the edited version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the validity of wudu' you need to have done at least the fard parts which are mentioned in ([5:6](https://legacy.quran.com/5/6)):

> you who have believed, when you rise to [perform] prayer, **wash your faces and your forearms to the elbows and wipe over your heads and wash your feet to the ankles**. And if you are in a state of janabah, then purify yourselves. But if you are ill or on a journey or one of you comes from the place of relieving himself or you have contacted women and do not find water, then seek clean earth and wipe over your faces and hands with it. Allah does not intend to make difficulty for you, but He intends to purify you and complete His favor upon you that you may be grateful.

If you have done so your wudu' is valid your skin may get dry afterwards it doesn't even play a role unless you have interrupted your wudu' in that case some madhhabs hold the opinion that as long as your skin shows some wetness you may go ahead else you need to restart from zero.

As for the case of performing wudu' and shaving the beard or shedding even if this might be considered as sinful or even haram by scholars. There's consensus that this doesn't per se break or invaldidate a wudu' performed before (as long as there's no other reason for which wudu' broke), but some scholars discussed whether or not one should re-do the washing of the body part which was "shaved". Islamweb offers a fatwa #[109587](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/109587)  on that in Arabaic quoting from a maliki book of fiqh the difference of opinion on the necessity of washing.